# How to run php script without all limits?

Tags: php

I know there are many questions, how to run php script without time execution limit, but im curious, how to run php script without any limitations. (i think there is something like max memory consumption, mysql timeout, etc...)

I have script, which is mapping my part of harddrive and reading directory and files content and storing some data into database. So im expectating that this script will take long time and huge chunk of memory.

So my question is, what should i set to "infinite" to get script running maximum posible duration?

as for now, im using this ini_set, but for some reason script ends before everything is finished. (and even before 40 minutes time limit which i set)

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2400);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 2400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2400);
```

Comment: Just this one `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Comment: Tahnks @Daan im trying it right know, but result will be know in 20 minutes. So there is realy no need for some mysql limit sets or maximum of runed php scripts or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to unset all limit at once.

The best you can do is to look at all the php.ini directive and try to figure out which applies to your system, and increase them to an unlimited value, or when not applicable, a very big value.

Here's a list of the core PHP directives: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

You have to remember that there's limit on the system too (ulimit on Linux) that can prevent the PHP process to grab enough memory / open enough files.

Here's the ulimit doc: http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

Don't for forget they vary from user to user.

---

Also, you could run your script with PHP-CLI (from a command line) as it doesn't have any limits enforced by the web server.

Comment: Thanks for link, its seems usefull to me. But its not exactly what im looking for. I think i browse enough my phpinfo() to set all values that i thought can limit me, but still im missing something...

Comment: Usually, when PHP stops for reaching a limit, it stops with an error (displayed). If you don't have, it could be the system's limit itself (ulimit on linux). Then it's another question.

Comment: As you said, it stops without error. I will doublecheck logs, but in browser there is nothing (and i have errors enabled as on dev version).

Comment: Check your ulimits. I've edited my post with a link.

Comment: good hint, i will give it a try. But im running it on windows server, so if im correct i need to check file descriptors (which i read that are equivalent to unix ulimits)

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini make max_execution_time = 0

Note: But it is not a good practice.